# CamelCase-aware backward-kill-word in readline

Tags: command-line, terminal, configuration, readline, inputrc

`backward-kill-word` is a readline action that deletes the previous alphanumeric word. For example, applying this action in the following scenario (`▯` indicates the position of the cursor)

```
echo hello-friend▯
```

results in

```
echo hello-▯
```

`backward-kill-word` is typically bound to `<Alt-Backspace>`, although this can be customized in readline's config file `~/.inputrc`.

My question is: is it possible to customize `backward-kill-word` so that it deletes back up to the first non-alphanumeric character, or the first capital letter? This way, it could be used to delete CamelCase words. For example, if I start with

```
echo HelloFriend▯
```

upon pressing `<Alt-Backspace>` I would like to obtain

```
echo Hello▯
```

Comment: IIYM Alt+Backspace instead of Alt+Esc

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have bound `<Esc>` to `<Backspace>` through xkb, that's why I was confused. I have edited to correct the mistake.

Comment: What does IIYM mean? I have searched it and the only thing that came up was the "Institute of Young Musicians", which I am assuming is not fitting here...

Comment: :-) sorry, I did mean ITYM (I think you meant)

Answer (score 1):

If switching to `zsh` is an option, you can use [`select-word-style` user-contributed widget](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Widgets) which allows you to select the word style for all the word motions and operations.

Add to `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
zle -N select-word-style
bindkey '\ez' select-word-style
select-word-style default
```

And press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to select alternative word styles:

```
$ echo HelloFriendAlt+Z
Word styles (hit return for more detail):
(b)ash (n)ormal (s)hell (w)hitespace (d)efault (q)uit
(B), (N), (S), (W) as above with subword matching
```

Then uppercase `B` would select a (annoying to me, but maybe familiar to you) `bash` style of word selection but with camel-case subword handling alter which (in `emacs` mode) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) would remove the `Friend` above or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> would move back to the start of that `Friend` word, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot switch to `zsh` because I do a lot of work on clusters which don't have it. Although I will note down this advantage of `zsh` for the future. Do you know if it is not possible to do something similar in `bash` and readline? I would accept a negative answer too. Thanks.